# Discrete frequency polygon over a bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to draw a frequency polygon over a bar plot with ggplot2. I use the commands below

```
library(ggplot2)
g <- ggplot(diamonds) + geom_bar(aes(cut))
g + geom_freqpoly(aes(as.numeric(cut)),binwidth=1)
```

but the polygon vertices are not on the center of the bars. I tried different binwidth without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove `as.numeric()` from `aes()` and then add `group=1` inside aes() to ensure that points are connected by line.

```
ggplot(diamonds) + geom_bar(aes(cut))+
          geom_freqpoly(aes(cut,group=1))
```

Or simply

```
ggplot(diamonds,aes(cut,group=1)) + geom_bar()+
          geom_freqpoly()
```

[image]