# Overlay a frequency polygon over a bar plot with non count stat

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I would like to overlay a frequency polygon over a bar plot where `stat = 'identity'` and not count. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182503/discrete-frequency-polygon-over-a-bar-plot) works with count data but not when you are using summarised data. Take this example below:

**Data**

```
data <- tibble(my_factors = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),
       total = c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120))
```

Group by factors and plot total

```
data %>% 
  group_by(my_factors) %>% 
  summarise(total = sum(total)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(my_factors, total)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

**Desired output**

In this case it's a fairly linear line but would a 'smooth' line also be possible?

[image]

Comment: A friendly reminder that `geom_col()` is shorthand for `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your problem.. but can't you just add `geom_freqpoly(stat = 'identity')`?

Comment: @Edo Thanks for highlighting this. It seems my data needed the extra `group = 1` otherwise a `geom_path` error is shown. `geom_freqpoly` seems to be working now.